# Download a file from aws s3 bucker in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

I am using `angularjs` . I want to implement a download functionality.

```
<button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title="download">
        <a href="link of the s3" download="downloaded">Download</a>
</button>
```

So, I have a controller and the service as well, But I am totally confused between this things. What is the way to download a file from s3 on a button click ? DO I need to call a rest service for that ?

Answer (score 1):

For downloading files from s3 you can use rest APIs provided by amazon for accessing s3 resources http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html

But for accessing those files your request should contain authorization string (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-auth-using-authorization-header.html) or you can use pre-signed URLs.

Your service call can generate those signatures/URLs at runtime with the help of your secret/access key for this you can write full algo provided by amazon or you can use amazon provided sdk(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingAWSSDK.html#specify-signature-version).